# android GPS location doesn't work?

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, android-gps

I'm new to android development and I tried 2 tutorials to get the current location but neither of them work for me. I get the exact expected layout but instead of showing the location, it appears to be totally blank as if the command that sets the text field doesn't exist. The logcat doesn't show any exception that's why I didn't post it. Everything else looks normal.
I thought it might be something related to the permissions that must be ran in realtime starting from android 6.0 but this tutorial that I've tried deals with that issue, besides doesn't the lack of permissions throw a security exception ?
Here are the two tutorials that I've followed exactly as they are:

http://demonuts.com/2016/12/30/get-current-location-android-studio/

http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/12/how-to-get-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android.html

Answer (score 0):

For maps to working you need to put google_maps_key into google_maps_api.xml which is under values folder. You get this key in google api manager.